# define anonymous enum with x-macros produces compilation error

Tags: c++, c, x-macros

Im working on a big project and I have a lot of errno macros.
I want to write a helper functions for the logger that stringify each of these errno to a string. i decided to use x-macros but Im getting compilation errors

in the first place the code was like this:

```
// project_errno.h
#define PROJECT_ERR_KEY_FAILURE                         12222
#define PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING                 12345
#define PROJECT_ERR_FAILED_TO_SETUP_ENC_KEY             14004
```

the way i sort it out is as the following:

- In a different file i places the x-macros:

```
// project_errno.hx
PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(PROJECT_ERR_KEY_FAILURE)                         12222
PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING)                 12345
PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(PROJECT_ERR_FAILED_TO_SETUP_ENC_KEY)             14004
```

- then I turned it into an enum:

```
// project_errno.h
enum {
#define PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(name, value) name=value,
#include "project_errno.hx"
#undef PROJECT_ERR_FUNC
};
```

- then i added a function that will be used by the logger:

```
// logging.h (declaration) and (definition) logging.c
const char* stringify_errno(int errno) {
    switch (errno) {
#define PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(name, value) case name: return #value ;
#include "project_errno.hx"
#undef PROJECT_ERR_FUNC
    }
}
```

So, looks pretty good, but i can't get it to compile, Im getting the following compilation errros:

```
project_errno.h:8:53: error: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
#define PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING                 12345
                                                        ^
..../project_errno.h:17:30: note: in definition of macro ‘PROJECT_ERR_FUNC’
#define PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(name, value) name=value,
                                      ^~~~
..../project_errno.hx:47:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING ’PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING,       12345)

project_errno.h:8:53: error: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant 
#define PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING                 12345
                                                        ^
..../project_errno.h:17:30: note: in definition of macro ‘PROJECT_ERR_FUNC’
#define PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(name, value) name=value,
                                      ^~~~
..../project_errno.hx:47:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING ’PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING,       12345)

project_errno.h:8:53: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant 
#define PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING                 12345
                                                        ^
..../project_errno.h:17:30: note: in definition of macro ‘PROJECT_ERR_FUNC’
#define PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(name, value) name=value,
                                      ^~~~
..../project_errno.hx:47:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING ’PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING,       12345)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ......../project_errno.h:20:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
};
^

..../project_errno.h:17:30: note: in definition of macro ‘PROJECT_ERR_FUNC’
#define PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(name, value) name=value,
                                      ^~~~
..../project_errno.hx:47:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING ’PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING,       12345)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can't understand why im getting those errors (im getting the same error message multiple time in the same compilation session), and i hope you guys could help me.
Also, if you have any other solution to solve the problem i intended to solve in the first place (using the errno macros and add a functions to stringify those errnos whenever Im adding an errno to the project [in only one place]), i'd love to hear about it  Thanks

Comment: Just copy&paste the code from the header into the file including it and you should see that a) you're passing the wrong number of parameters, and b) assuming the compiler would consider the second parameter empty, you'd get `12222 = , 12222 12345 ...`. Also what are those backticks doing there at the end of the last constants?

Comment: im not sure what do you mean. what do you call the header and what do you call the file (There are project_errno.h and project_errno.hx, which of them you call what) 
And about your highlights:
a) when do i pass the wrong number of parameters? i always pass 2 arguments (name, value)
b) why the compiler will consider the second parameter empty? Im giving each of the x-macro both of the parameters.

It's seems like you see something that i don't see and i'd love to know about that :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd follow the recipe shown in the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) about X Macros:

> **Implementation**
>
> An X macro application consists of two parts:
>
> 1. The definition of the list's elements.
> 2. Expansion(s) of the list to generate fragments of declarations or statements.
>
> The list is defined by a macro or header file (named, `LIST`) which generates no code by itself, but merely consists of a sequence of invocations of a macro (classically named `X`) with the elements' data. Each expansion of `LIST` is preceded by a definition of `X` with the syntax for a list element. The invocation of `LIST` expands `X` for each element in the list.

In particular the second example, the one with X macro as argument

> Pass name of the worker macro into the list macro. This both avoids defining an obscurely named macro (`X`), and alleviates the need to undefine it.

Which, in OP's use case, leads to the following three files:

```
// project_errno.h
#ifndef PROJECT_ERRNO_H
#define PROJECT_ERRNO_H

#define FOR_EACH_ERR_ID_VALUE_PAIR(DO) \
    DO(PROJECT_ERR_KEY_FAILURE,             12222) \
    DO(PROJECT_ERR_CIPHER_ZERO_PADDING,     12345) \
    DO(PROJECT_ERR_FAILED_TO_SETUP_ENC_KEY, 14004)

#define DEFINE_ENUM_ITEM(err, value) err = value,
enum project_errs {
    FOR_EACH_ERR_ID_VALUE_PAIR( DEFINE_ENUM_ITEM )
};
#undef DEFINE_ENUM_ITEM

#endif
```

```
// logging.h
#ifndef LOGGING_H
#define LOGGING_H

const char* stringify_errno(int errno);

#endif
```

```
// logging.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "project_errno.h"

#define STRINGIFY_ERR_VALUE_NAME(name, value) case name: \
    return "[" #value "] " #name;
 
const char* stringify_errno(int errno)
{
    switch (errno) {
        FOR_EACH_ERR_ID_VALUE_PAIR(STRINGIFY_ERR_VALUE_NAME)
        default:
            return "[-----] UNKWOWN";    
    }
}

#undef STRINGIFY_ERR_VALUE_NAME
```

Testable here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/aNJCI7lQihkFnYzp

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer:

I was able to generate the enum using

```
enum {
#define PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(name) , name =
PROJECT_ERR_START_OF_ENUM = -1
#include "project_errno.hx"
#undef PROJECT_ERR_FUNC
};
```

but had to remove the backtick at the end of `project_errno.hx`. The above code will only work if you **do not include** `project_errno.h` before.

A complete minimum working program would be

```
enum {
#define PROJECT_ERR_FUNC(name) , name =
PROJECT_ERR_START_OF_ENUM = -1
#include "project_errno.hx"
#undef PROJECT_ERR_FUNC
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << PROJECT_ERR_KEY_FAILURE << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

that will print `12222`.

Comment: First, it didn't help :( . im getting the same error messages but with an additional new line, among all the mess of that error message

Second, the solution you suggest is needed where we use it all within the same file. but here, im using 2 separated files so I don't need to define that FOREACH but only put "plain text" in project_errno.hx and just include it

Comment: @danwgh In order to get this to work, you have to *start small*: Start by copying my minimum working program and get it to work. Then move on from there...

Comment: I don't understand how could i get it to work. the macro function, as you defined it, does not even produce the 'value'. 
please notice that Im using non-consecutive numbers, so i can't trust the enum to generate these values by itself..